# What Am I Missing In This Code?

Tags: javascript

I am new to this, and can't figure out where I've gone wrong. When I click the button nothing is happening. I might have added too much extra stuff, I can't really tell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" CONTENT="text/javascript" />
    <html ng-app>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="victory.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var Walmart = (function () {
function Walmart(http, zone) {
    this.stores = [];
    this.storeid = document.getElementById("storenum").value
    this.walmart = {
            query: [
                'http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=',
                '&store=' + this.storeid
            ],
             };
    this.zone = zone;
    this.http = http;  
    console.log(this.walmart);

    };

 var query = document.getElementById("search").value;

Walmart.prototype.getWalmartStoreQuery = function (query) {
    return this.http.get(this.walmart.store.query[0] + query + this.walmart.store.query[1] ).map(function (res) { return res.json(); });

</script>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="storenum" id="storenum"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="search" id="search"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button onclick="getWalmartStoreQuery">Test</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Check the console, any error messages?

Comment: the only thing that comes as an error is "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "not found"

Comment: so no error message when you click the button?

Comment: correct. I'm not sure why but literally nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Please try to create a better title when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to wire up an event handler to an HTML element via an HTML attribute, the code should be:

`onclick="getWalmartStoreQuery()"` not, `onclick="getWalmartStoreQuery"`

But, that is not really the recommended approach. This form of event wiring is called "inline event wiring" and:

1. Creates spaghetti code which doesn't promote good separation of concerns and makes debugging harder.
2. Creates a hidden global anonymous proxy function around your code that manipulates the `this` binding to Global.
3. Doesn't follow the [W3C DOM Level 2 Event Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration) and isn't as robust as that model prescribes.

To wire an event handling callback the more modern way, do this in your JavaScript as soon as the DOM is loaded:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("theButtonsId");

// Do not put parenthesis after the callback name as
// you are only trying to reference it here, not call it
btn.addEventListener("click", callBackFunctionName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Test this:

```js
var walmart = function(http, zone){
      if(!(this instanceof walmart)){
       return new walmart(http, zone);
      }
    
        this.stores = [];
        this.storeid = document.getElementById("storenum").value
        this.walmart = {
            query: [
                    'http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=',
                    '&store=' + this.storeid
              ],
          };
        this.zone = zone;
        this.http = http;
    };
    
    walmart.prototype.getWalmartStoreQuery = function () {
     var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
        return this.http.get(this.walmart.store.query[0] + query + this.walmart.store.query[1] ).map(function (res) {
         return res.json();
        });
    };
```

```html
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="storenum" id="storenum"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="search" id="search"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button onclick="walmart.prototype.getWalmartStoreQuery()">Test</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -3):

You can not instantiate a function from a class in the onclick event of the button

Comment: So how would I go about this?

Comment: You have to pass the "http" and the "zone" as well:

Comment: walmart(http, zone).getWalmartStoreQuery()